# Getting terminal size when running with "watch" in Linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I have this simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    struct winsize w;
    if (!ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &w)) {
        printf("width %d\n", w.ws_col);
    } else {
        printf("%s", strerror(errno));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which if run from the terminal itself, will return the size of the terminal window, but for some reason, if run through the `watch` command, it just fails on the ioctl() which returns INAPPROPRIATE IOCTL FOR DEVICE.

Any idea why? What would be the most reliable way of getting the terminal window size?

Comment: I suggest you check [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) first... Like `isatty(fileno(stdout))`. My guess is that `FILENO_STDOUT` (the standard output descriptor) doesn't go to a terminal but rather a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, that stdout of your program is no longer the terminal, but a *pipe* to `watch`, which will collect the program output and display it. Thus, you cannot determine the width from the stdout filedescriptor.

`stdin`, however, is still connected to the terminal, so you can use `fileno(stdin)` instead to get the correct terminal size:

```
if (!ioctl(fileno(stdin), TIOCGWINSZ, &w)) {
    printf("width %d\n", w.ws_col);
```

Comment: Often, `stderr` is the best file stream (descriptor) to use.  You can also check whether the device behind the descriptor is a terminal —`isatty()`, IIRC.